# Bitcoin address duplicate when creating using a SHA256 hash?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, bitcoin-testnet

What happen if 2 different persons use the same SHA265 hash to create a bitcoin address?

Please see the example below with bitcoinjs-lib

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.js#L19

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/is-each-bitcoin-address-unique  Too bad we cannot flag question as duplicate to other stackexchange sites.